# Perform $.ajax like POST request with paw-app

Tags: post, paw-app

How Do I create a POST request with paw that is equal to a (jquery) ajax `$.ajax({type: "POST", (...)});`request?

I thought I could set the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` to `XMLHttpRequest` but it does not work.

Whats the basic difference between an ajax/javascript POST and a regular POST from a form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simulate a POST request made via Ajax, what you need to do is to add an HTTP header:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

1. Set the request method to POST
2. Enter the URL
3. Add the header mentioned above

[image: Send Ajax-like requests in Paw]

Then enter the body in the **Body** tab, using the **Form URL-Encoded** mode:

[image: Send Ajax-like requests in Paw]

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a post from a form, you are executing a submit event. In case you did not override the browser's default behavior for form submission at least for the case you are talking about, then the browser will execute it as an html post, which is a full postback. It sends the request and when the response arrives, it will be the new content of the page.

If you do a post with Javascript, then a request is sent and upon response, your callback will be executed, if existent.